# Cant see the history and profile for all the query id in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

In the history tab of snowflakes web interface, i am selecting the filter 'Query Id' and providing the id.Its working for some "Query Id" but not providing the details for some "Query Id" .
I understand it is the problem of  not having right permissions/privileges.What is role that I should be having in order to see the details of any/all "Quer Id" in the history tab regardless of who ever runs/owns them.

Should my role must have access to vw and database on which the query belongs to?(in order to view the details in history tab)

Comment: Have you tried a role with MONITOR rights on the respective VW?  https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#virtual-warehouse-privileges

Answer (score 2):

To answer your query

"What is role that I should be having in order to see the details of any/all "Quer Id" in the history tab regardless of who ever runs/owns them."

Please create a new role and grant below two privs then assign that to the user . You can see all the historical queries of that warehouse .

Add both the privs to the specific WH :     MONITOR / USAGE

```
 GRANT USAGE ON WAREHOUSE COMPUTE_WH TO ROLE monitor_execution_new;
 GRANT MONITOR ON WAREHOUSE COMPUTE_WH TO ROLE monitor_execution_new;
```

Thanks,
Palash Chatterjee

---

edited on 12/05/2020

---

Just to answer your comment regarding, "is there any default role to see other users executed queries"

"NO", ACCOUNTADMIN is the only role who can by default see the execution of all the users query execution without additional assignment of privs

Note : Even if Accountadmin can see the query execution details they can not export result of other user's query

***Additionally***

As you might have seen the snowflake role hierarchy (USERADMIN got added recently on April 2020)

[image]

Comment: Can't we have a role that has usage and monitor privileges on all the warehouse?Do we have any standard/Predefined role that helps in monitoring   all warehouse some thing like "account admin"  to  monitor  in snowflakes ?

Comment: From the set of system defined roles Accountadmin can see all the query execution details , no such default role , you need to create a custom one . As per snowflake suggestion , one should not have accountadmin as default role .

Answer (score 0):

Please check box two options under the Filters in your History Tab

Include client-generated statements
Include queries executed by user tasks
[image]

Comment: Please make sure you have no extra spaces to the start and end of the query Id

Comment: Also please check if the query is executed within 14 days.https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/ui-history.html#using-the-history-page-to-monitor-queries